# Searching and replacing with file contents

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to search for characters in file and replace with file containing contents: search for `ktr_updater` in file and replace with file contents from another file using Unix commands.

```
sed -i 's/ktr_updater/'"$ktrupdate"'/g' samplejob.kjb
```

Comment: Would the string `ktr_updater` occur within one line in the original file, and if so, should only that part of the line be replaced by the contents of the other file?

Comment: yes thatis the req

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi -e 'BEGIN{local $/; $r = <STDIN>} s/ktr_updater/$r/g
            ' file < other-file
```

Would edit `file` `i`n-place and `s`ubstitude every (`g`lobally) occurrence of `ktr_updater` with `$r`, `$r` having been initialled at the `BEGIN`ning with what could be read from `STDIN` (in one go as the record delimiter was unset, by declaring it without a value `local`ly to the BEGIN statement), stdin having been redirected to the `other-file`.

With GNU `sed` or compatible, you could do the same by storing the content of the file in a shell variable, [convert it to something that is suitable as a `sed` `s` command replacement](/a/129063) and call `sed` with that:

```
repl=$(cat other-file; echo .); repl=${repl%.}
escaped_repl=$(printf '%s\n' "$repl" | sed 's:[\/&]:\\&:g;$!s/$/\\/')
sed -i "s/ktr_updater/$escaped_repl/g" file
```